How to do exponentiation or roots in IDA Freeware 8.4's scripting language IDC?
I have to calculate square roots in IDC (to calculate distances between things when a breakpoint fires), but I am unable to find out how to do that. I tried:

Obvious candidates like sqrt(4), 4**0.5, 4^0.5
Googling (apparently this is not a common problem)
Searching through idc.idc (but I did not find any common math functions)
Reading the IDC expressions documentation (but it mentions only "almost all C operations" which exponentiations and roots are not)

Do I have to modify my binary to include an sqrt function and call it through dbg_appcall?
